How can I clean up my code? New to coding
Im new to coding and this is one of my first programs I've made, but it feels very clunky and I want to know how to write code more efficiently. I'm running on IntelliJ IDEA with JDK SE 8.
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] OxO = {{"@","@","@","@","@","@","@","@"},
                          {"@","P","O"," "," "," "," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@"," "," "," ","O","O"," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@","O"," ","O","O"," "," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@"," "," ","O","X"," "," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@"," ","O","O","O","O"," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@"," "," "," "," "," "," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@","@","@","@","@","@","@","@"}};
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;

        System.out.println("Enter 'w','a','s', or 'd' to play. You are 'P' and your objective is to get to the 'X'");

        while(OxO[4][4] != "P") {

            System.out.println(OxO[0][0]+OxO[0][1]+OxO[0][2]+OxO[0][3]+OxO[0][4]+OxO[0][5]+OxO[0][6]+OxO[0][7]);
            System.out.println(OxO[1][0]+OxO[1][1]+OxO[1][2]+OxO[1][3]+OxO[1][4]+OxO[1][5]+OxO[1][6]+OxO[1][7]);
            System.out.println(OxO[2][0]+OxO[2][1]+OxO[2][2]+OxO[2][3]+OxO[2][4]+OxO[2][5]+OxO[2][6]+OxO[2][7]);
            System.out.println(OxO[3][0]+OxO[3][1]+OxO[3][2]+OxO[3][3]+OxO[3][4]+OxO[3][5]+OxO[3][6]+OxO[3][7]);
            System.out.println(OxO[4][0]+OxO[4][1]+OxO[4][2]+OxO[4][3]+OxO[4][4]+OxO[4][5]+OxO[4][6]+OxO[4][7]);
            System.out.println(OxO[5][0]+OxO[5][1]+OxO[5][2]+OxO[5][3]+OxO[5][4]+OxO[5][5]+OxO[5][6]+OxO[5][7]);
            System.out.println(OxO[6][0]+OxO[6][1]+OxO[6][2]+OxO[6][3]+OxO[6][4]+OxO[6][5]+OxO[6][6]+OxO[6][7]);
            System.out.println(OxO[7][0]+OxO[7][1]+OxO[7][2]+OxO[7][3]+OxO[7][4]+OxO[7][5]+OxO[7][6]+OxO[7][7]);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String movement = scanner.nextLine();
            if(Objects.equals(movement, "a")) {
                int old = x;
                x = x - 1;
                OxO[y][8] = OxO[y][old];
                if(Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "O") || Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "@")) {
                    x = x+1;
                } else {
                    OxO[y][x] = OxO[y][8];
                    OxO[y][old] = " ";
                }
            } else if (Objects.equals(movement, "d")) {
                int old = x;
                x = x + 1;
                OxO[y][8] = OxO[y][old];
                if(Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "O") || Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "@")) {
                    x = x-1;
                } else {
                    OxO[y][x] = OxO[y][8];
                    OxO[y][old] = " ";
                }
            } else if (Objects.equals(movement, "w")) {
                int old = y;
                y = y - 1;
                OxO[y][8] = OxO[old][x];
                if(Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "O") || Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "@")) {
                    y = y+1;
                } else {
                    OxO[y][x] = OxO[y][8];
                    OxO[old][x] = " ";
                }
            } else if (Objects.equals(movement, "s")) {
                int old = y;
                y = y + 1;
                OxO[y][8] = OxO[old][x];
                if(Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "O") || Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "@")) {
                    y = y-1;
                } else {
                    OxO[y][x] = OxO[y][8];
                    OxO[old][x] = " ";
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

        }

        System.out.println(OxO[0][0]+OxO[0][1]+OxO[0][2]+OxO[0][3]+OxO[0][4]+OxO[0][5]+OxO[0][6]+OxO[0][7]);
        System.out.println(OxO[1][0]+OxO[1][1]+OxO[1][2]+OxO[1][3]+OxO[1][4]+OxO[1][5]+OxO[1][6]+OxO[1][7]);
        System.out.println(OxO[2][0]+OxO[2][1]+OxO[2][2]+OxO[2][3]+OxO[2][4]+OxO[2][5]+OxO[2][6]+OxO[2][7]);
        System.out.println(OxO[3][0]+OxO[3][1]+OxO[3][2]+OxO[3][3]+OxO[3][4]+OxO[3][5]+OxO[3][6]+OxO[3][7]);
        System.out.println(OxO[4][0]+OxO[4][1]+OxO[4][2]+OxO[4][3]+OxO[4][4]+OxO[4][5]+OxO[4][6]+OxO[4][7]);
        System.out.println(OxO[5][0]+OxO[5][1]+OxO[5][2]+OxO[5][3]+OxO[5][4]+OxO[5][5]+OxO[5][6]+OxO[5][7]);
        System.out.println(OxO[6][0]+OxO[6][1]+OxO[6][2]+OxO[6][3]+OxO[6][4]+OxO[6][5]+OxO[6][6]+OxO[6][7]);
        System.out.println(OxO[7][0]+OxO[7][1]+OxO[7][2]+OxO[7][3]+OxO[7][4]+OxO[7][5]+OxO[7][6]+OxO[7][7]);
        System.out.println("\nYou have done it!");

    }

}


I've removed some useless lines that wouldn't affect anything, but that's all that I could come up with. Also, if there are any tips you could give to a beginner like me, that would be appreciated. Thank you!

recommended to take the [tour] and visit the [help]. Code review questions are better posted in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - also check its tour and help center

Is there a reason you're using Java 8 instead of a more recent version?

Looking at your code it seems like you can avoid checking for the same thing, on the different movement types.
The first thing is using java forloops to print the game state to the user, making the game scalable and easier to print.
Second thing is performing the movement first, and then checking if it hit the border, as the if-statements check the same thing, for each movement. This also makes it possible for easier handling.
Third is that you can access the equal operator on the string directly, making the condition smaller and more readable.
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] OxO = { { "@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@" },
                { "@", "P", "O", " ", " ", " ", " ", "@", "", " " },
                { "@", " ", " ", " ", "O", "O", " ", "@", "", " " },
                { "@", "O", " ", "O", "O", " ", " ", "@", "", " " },
                { "@", " ", " ", "O", "X", " ", " ", "@", "", " " },
                { "@", " ", "O", "O", "O", "O", " ", "@", "", " " },
                { "@", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", "@", "", " " },
                { "@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@", "@" } };
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;

        System.out.println("Enter 'w','a','s', or 'd' to play. You are 'P' and your objective is to get to the 'X'");

        while (OxO[4][4] != "P") {

            for (int i = 0; i < OxO.length; i++) {
                String str = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < OxO[i].length; j++) {
                    str += OxO[i][j];
                }
                System.out.println(str);
            }

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String movement = scanner.nextLine();
            int oldx = x;
            int oldy = y;

            if (movement.equals("a")) {
                x = x - 1;
            } else if (movement.equals("d")) {
                x = x + 1;
            } else if (movement.equals("w")) {
                y = y - 1;
            } else if (movement.equals("s")) {
                y = y + 1;
            }

            if(Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "O") || Objects.equals(OxO[y][x], "@")) {
                x = oldx;
                y = oldy;
            } else{
                OxO[oldy][oldx] = " ";
            }
            OxO[y][x] = "P";
            
            System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < OxO.length; i++) {
            String str = "";
            for (int j = 0; j < OxO[i].length; j++) {
                str += OxO[i][j];
            }
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        System.out.println("\nYou have done it!");

    }
}


I would consider using for loops for printing the board, and since you are new to coding, reading up about functions/methods, and extracting the printing of the board into a function, like this:
private static void printBoard(String[][] board) {
    for (String[] row : board) {
        for (String cell : row) {
            System.out.print(cell);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
}

I would also consider using a switch statement instead of if statements.
I have an example of how you may improve you code further, full code:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[][] OxO = {{"@","@","@","@","@","@","@","@"},
                          {"@","P","O"," "," "," "," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@"," "," "," ","O","O"," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@","O"," ","O","O"," "," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@"," "," ","O","X"," "," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@"," ","O","O","O","O"," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@"," "," "," "," "," "," ","@",""," "},
                          {"@","@","@","@","@","@","@","@"}};
        int x = 1;
        int y = 1;

        System.out.println("Enter 'w','a','s', or 'd' to play. You are 'P' and your objective is to get to the 'X'");

        while(OxO[4][4] != "P") {

            printBoard(OxO);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String movement = scanner.nextLine();
            int oldx = x, oldy = y;
        
            switch (movement) {
                case "w":
                    x--;
                    break;
                case "a":
                    y--;
                    break;
                case "s":
                    x++;
                    break;
                case "d":
                    y++;
                    break;
            }
            if ((OxO[x][y] != "@" && OxO[x][y] != "O")) {
                OxO[oldx][oldy] = " ";
                OxO[x][y] = "P";
            } else {
                x = oldx;
                y = oldy;
            }

        }
        printBoard(OxO);
        System.out.println("\nYou have done it!");
    }

    private static void printBoard(String[][] board) {
        for (String[] row : board) {
            for (String cell : row) {
                System.out.print(cell);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
    }
}


Your program is a good starting point, but there are some areas where you can improve both efficiency and readability
Some general coding norms to use:

Use a for loop for printing the gridInstead of manually printing each row of the grid.
Instead of hardcoding values like 4 for row and column indices, use constants or variables to make your code more readable and maintainable.
You can simplify your movement logic by first checking if the movement is valid, and then updating the position if it is.
Use equals() for String comparison Instead of == or != for String comparison, use the equals() method. Here == compares the memory addresses and not the string literal intsself.

import java.util.*;

public class Game {

    private static final int GRID_SIZE = 8;
    private static final int PLAYER_ROW = 1;
    private static final int PLAYER_COL = 1;
    private static final char PLAYER_CHAR = 'P';
    private static final char EMPTY_CHAR = ' ';
    private static final char WALL_CHAR = '@';
    private static final char OBJECTIVE_CHAR = 'X';
    private static final char OBSTACLE_CHAR = 'O';

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] grid = initializeGrid();

        System.out.println("Enter 'w','a','s', or 'd' to play. You are 'P' and your objective is to get to the 'X'");

        int playerRow = PLAYER_ROW;
        int playerCol = PLAYER_COL;

        while (grid[playerRow][playerCol] != OBJECTIVE_CHAR) {
            printGrid(grid);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String movement = scanner.nextLine();
            movePlayer(grid, movement, playerRow, playerCol);
        }

        printGrid(grid);
        System.out.println("\nYou have done it!");
    }

    private static char[][] initializeGrid() {
        return new char[][]{
                {'@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@'},
                {'@', 'P', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'},
                {'@', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'O', 'O', ' ', '@'},
                {'@', 'O', ' ', 'O', 'O', ' ', ' ', '@'},
                {'@', ' ', ' ', 'O', 'X', ' ', ' ', '@'},
                {'@', ' ', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', ' ', '@'},
                {'@', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '@'},
                {'@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@', '@'}
        };
    }

    private static void printGrid(char[][] grid) {
        for (char[] row : grid) {
            for (char cell : row) {
                System.out.print(cell);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void movePlayer(char[][] grid, String movement, int playerRow, int playerCol) {
        switch (movement) {
            case "a":
                move(grid, playerRow, playerCol, 0, -1);
                break;
            case "d":
                move(grid, playerRow, playerCol, 0, 1);
                break;
            case "w":
                move(grid, playerRow, playerCol, -1, 0);
                break;
            case "s":
                move(grid, playerRow, playerCol, 1, 0);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid movement. Please enter 'w', 'a', 's', or 'd'.");
        }
    }

    private static void move(char[][] grid, int playerRow, int playerCol, int rowChange, int colChange) {
        int newRow = playerRow + rowChange;
        int newCol = playerCol + colChange;
        if (isValidMove(grid, newRow, newCol)) {
            grid[playerRow][playerCol] = EMPTY_CHAR;
            grid[newRow][newCol] = PLAYER_CHAR;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid move! You can't go there.");
        }
    }

    private static boolean isValidMove(char[][] grid, int row, int col) {
        return row >= 0 && row < GRID_SIZE && col >= 0 && col < GRID_SIZE && grid[row][col] != WALL_CHAR && grid[row][col] != OBSTACLE_CHAR;
    }
}

This version of the code uses methods to improve readability and maintainability. It also simplifies the movement logic and utilizes constants to avoid magic numbers. And it prints the grid using nested loops, making the code more concise.
